# PHP get the camera used on target image using exif_read_data

Tags: php, metadata

I am attempting to get the camera used on a target image using PHP `exif_read_data` below code returns all available metadata that image has, but i am currently confused on how to get the specific data that i need which is MODEL of the camera used to take the photo, any suggestion would be great thanks!

```
<?php

$exif = exif_read_data('382.jpg', 'IFD0');
echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

$exif = exif_read_data('382.jpg', 0, true);

foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {

    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {

        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";

    }
}
?>
```

My Output is below.

```
Image contains headers
FILE.FileName: 382.jpg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1503356646
FILE.FileSize: 366174
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF, GPS, INTEROP, MAKERNOTE
COMPUTED.html: width="950" height="712"
COMPUTED.Height: 712
COMPUTED.Width: 950
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1
COMPUTED.CCDWidth: 6mm
COMPUTED.ApertureFNumber: f/3.4
COMPUTED.UserComment:
COMPUTED.UserCommentEncoding: UNDEFINED
COMPUTED.Thumbnail.FileType: 2
COMPUTED.Thumbnail.MimeType: image/jpeg
IFD0.ImageDescription:
IFD0.Make: Canon
IFD0.Model: Canon PowerShot SX50 HS
IFD0.Orientation: 1
IFD0.XResolution: 180/1
IFD0.YResolution: 180/1
IFD0.ResolutionUnit: 2
IFD0.DateTime: 2015:03:24 13:15:55
IFD0.Artist:
IFD0.YCbCrPositioning: 2
IFD0.Copyright:
IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 268
IFD0.GPS_IFD_Pointer: 5016
THUMBNAIL.Compression: 6
THUMBNAIL.XResolution: 180/1
THUMBNAIL.YResolution: 180/1
THUMBNAIL.ResolutionUnit: 2
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormat: 5130
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 8036
```

Comment: is "IFD0.Model: Canon PowerShot SX50 HS" not right?

Comment: @Asleepace yes its correct my problem is how can i echo just the IFD0.Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the value of a dictionary with a key, just do `$dict['key']` and if that value happens to be another dictionary you can keep going `$dict['key1']['key2']['key3']`...

```
echo($exif['IFD0']['Model']);
```

Comment: *"Wouldn't it just be"* - I would change that to something that holds more confidence ;-) since it is the correct answer. Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45829345/1

Comment: Thanks its correct sorry guys for not getting than.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ya I just didn't test it out, but I updated it!